# Run service using sudo in bash/shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I have to run **apollo-broker-service** using **bash/shell script**.

For this i am using following script

```
#!/bin/bash

if pidof -x "apollo" >/dev/null; then
echo "Apollo MQTT is Running."
exit 0
else
echo "Apollo MQTT is Stopped."
sudo service apollo-broker-service start
exit 2
fi
```

If my service is stopped. It is not start "apollo-broker-service" service.

I already add the following line in **/etc/sudoers**

```
guest ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

I am using CentOS 7.

Comment: What *does* happen when you run that script? What does it output? What account is running that script? What does running that script with `bash -x $script` output?

Comment: @EtanReisner guest user run this script. When this script is run there is no error only print "Apollo MQTT is Stopped."

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried "bash -x $(sudo service apollo-broker-service start)" but nothing change.

Comment: That's not the command I told you to run. Though the command I said isn't likely to help much in this case. What does the service script look like? Also I expect your problem might be that `service` != `/usr/sbin/service` and `sudo` is picky.

Answer (score -2):

```
strace ./apollo-broker-service
```

this should give you an answer why it does not work. IMO it is related to permissions.